# creating orderer genesis block without cryptogen

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am currently trying to build a production hyperledger-fabric setup. Therefore I am using a CA instead of cryptogen. 
My structure looks like this:

- orderer
- org1

  - peer0.org1
  - peer1.org1
- org2

  - peer0.org2
  - peer1.org2

and I have 2 CAs (1 for every org). 
I have registered and enrolled orderer, peer0.org1, peer1.org1 and Org1Admin @CA1
and peer0.org2, peer1.org2 and Org2Admin @CA2.
The orderer has ROOT_CERTS of both CAs.

But how can I create the orderer genesis block based of those MSPs?
The configtx.yaml asks for an 'MSPDir' when describing the organizations, but I don't have an MSP directory for the organization itself, I only got the MSPs of the identites. Do I have to set up a specific folder structure for this?

Answer (score 2):

you should create a `msp` directory for each of the organizations, including `admincerts` and `cacerts`.

if your tls is enable, you need `tlscacerts`.

if you have Intermediate CA, you need `intermediatecerts` too.

you can read [this](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/msp.html#msp-setup-on-the-peer-orderer-side) document for complete information.

Comment: Where do I get the tlscacerts from? I got those for every "profile" by using --enrollment.profile tls, but which certificate shall I take to represent an organization?

Comment: you should have two kinds of certificate authorities. one for TLS communications and one for each organization. cacerts is the certificate of the organization CA, and tlscacerts is for the certificate of communications CA. if you use only one, just copy it in both folders!

Comment: Why do I need an extra CA for TLS communication, I thought I have the 2 Org-CAs for TLS communication?

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually setup the MSP folder structure for an organization. Typically for any organization without TLS enabled and no Intermediate CA, it should have cacerts folder, admincerts folder. cacerts folder root CA certificates, admin certs hold the admin certificates for that organization.

You need to point MSPDir in configtx.yaml to this organization msp folder.